# Não está aceitando caracteres especial via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Criei um arquivo **_ScriptsPartial** e dentro desse arquivo tem código javascript.

Segue arquivo **_Layout**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <partial name="_Favicons" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
</head>
<body>
    <partial name="_ScriptsPartial" />
</body>
</html>
```

Segue o código do arquivo **_ScriptsPartial**:

```
$('div.dropdown-menu')
    .append('<h1><span class="badge badge-secondary">Notificação</span></h1>');
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse problema acontece somente pelo código javascript.

Já converti a codificação para utf-8 do arquivo **_ScriptPartial** e veja resultado do editor VS2017:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma solução ?

Comment: Qual é a codificação do seu arquivo?

Comment: @lazyFox aqui está como **ANSI**, Visual Studio cria esse arquivo padrão.

Comment: Troca para `UTF-8`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Vou tem que alterar a codificação para **UTF-8** usando bloco de nota ao criar novos arquivos do Visual Studio 2017 ?

Comment: To falando do html gerado `<head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Aqui está como `<meta charset="utf-8" />`

Answer (score 0):

Altere o seu arquivo para utilizar a codificação `utf-8`.

Veja este [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2017) de como alterar a codificação no Visual Studio
Pode sempre utilizar um programa externo para alterar a codificação como por exemplo o notepad++

Comment: Não funcionou, eu converti para utf-8, do arquivo `_ScriptsPartial`, o próprio editor do Visual Studio não reconheceu caracteres especial.

Comment: Favor olhar minha perguntei, eu acabei de editar

Comment: Não uso o Visual Studio, mas dúvido que o editor não reconheça os caracteres. Já apagou os caracteres estranhos e voltou a escrever de novo agora com a codificação de utf-8?

Comment: Exclui arquivo e criei novamente, aparentemente está funcionando normal com caracteres especial. Fui olhar a codificação está como **utf-8**, não sei porque no arquivo anterior, o VS2017 criou com a codificação **ANSI**, muito estranho. Seria um bug ?

Comment: É possível ou alguma predefinição do seu IDE.